# Representation of negative numbers in memory

Tags: go

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var a, b int8 = -4, 4
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", a)

    fmt.Printf("%08b\n", a)

    fmt.Printf("%08b\n", b)
    //fmt.Println("a and b have same sign?", (a^b) >= 0)
}
```

---

gives output with minus sign:

```
-100
-0000100
00000100
```

---

How to view binary representation of negative number `-4`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see [two's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary representation, this would work:

```
var aUnsigned = uint8(a)
fmt.Printf("%08b\n", aUnsigned)
```

Output:

```
11111100
```